# "Missing argument for parameter #1 in call" error in UIAlertAction handler (swift2.1)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

i am trying to add simple action to UIAlertAction in swift2.1 , but i get "Missing argument for parameter #1 in call" error when deploy project, i try diffrent ways and searched a lot, but cant find right answer.
this is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController 
{
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "menu", message: "", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    internal func signOut()
    {
        self.preferences.setValue( nil , forKey: "nationalid")   
    }

    let buttonOne = UIAlertAction(title: "sign out", style: .Default) { action in
        print("Button One Pressed")
        signOut() // get error
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        alertController.addAction(buttonOne)
    }
}
```

but get "Missing argument for parameter #1 in call" error in specified line.

Answer (score 0):

i found my silly mistake, i will define my UIAlertAction in viewDidLoad() function, i change the code there and problem being solved:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController 
{
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "menu", message: "", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    internal func signOut()
    {
        self.preferences.setValue( nil , forKey: "nationalid")   
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    let buttonOne = UIAlertAction(title: "sign out", style: .Default) { action in
        print("Button One Pressed")
        signOut() 
    }

        alertController.addAction(buttonOne)
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add the presentViewController as well to display it.

Answer (score 0):

You have write this function inside the viewDidLoad or inside a function.

For example:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

       let alertController = UIAlertController()


       let OKAction =  UIAlertAction(title: "Sign out", style: .Default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
             signOut() 
       }
       alertController.addAction(OKAction)

       self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
   }
```

Hope this will be helpful